# Running chromium without desktop environment

Tags: gpio, screen, kiosk

I just installed Raspbian lite on my RPI 3.
I only need to run Chromium so I do not need a desktop environment.
Here's the screen I use : https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(B)

What I tried:

I installed xserver-xorg and xinit. My plan was to run `startx chromium-browser` on startup.
However, I cannot run X because it throws me the following error: `no screens found`, event if I installed the drivers and I see text on it.
Btw, `xrandr --display :0` tells me `can't open display :0`.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this through SSH? if you are in a SSH terminal try 
`export DISPLAY=:0`
if that doesn't work try 
`export DISPLAY=:0.0`
then run your command, this tells bash to run the command on display 0 not the current terminal.

hope this helps.

also I just went through this, kinda. you can make the desktop look like a splash screen image and completely remove the taskbar or remove both the desktop and the taskbar all together.

edit this file.

 

`sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` 


comment out the first line to remove the task bar, comment out the second line to remove the desktop.

mind you this may not work with your setup as I still have my desktop installed. and I auto login to the desktop.